# Finding $n$ such that $x_n$ is a prime number

Tags: number-theory

If the number $x_n$ is in the form of $1010101...1$ has $n$ ones .How to find each $n$ such that $x_n$ is a prime number

Comment: You want to find all such $n$? $101$ is a prime number.

Comment: Yes I want to find each $n$ that make $x_n$ a prime number

Comment: Note that $$x_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}100^k=\frac{100^n-1}{99}.$$ That may help you in determining more explicitly which ones work and which ones don't.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure $n$ has to be prime.  If $n=ab,x_a|x_n$ and $x_b|x_n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is $x_n$ is prime $\iff n=2$:

1. $101$ is prime.
2. If $n$ is even then $101\mid x_n$ (see Mike's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/finding-n-such-that-x-n-is-a-prime-number/344029#comment739362_344006)).
3. If $n=2k+1$ then $x_n=\overbrace{11\ldots1}^n\times\overbrace{90909\ldots09}^{k \text{ nines}}1$.

---

Proof of (3):
From  Cameron Buie's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/finding-n-such-that-x-n-is-a-prime-number/344029#comment739361_344006) (or by direct multiplication) it follows that 
$\color{blue}{11}\times \color{blue}{x_n}=\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{2n}=
\overbrace{\color{blue}{11\ldots1}}^{n}\times\color{blue}{1}\overbrace{\color{blue}{00\ldots0}}^{2k \text{ zeros}}\color{blue}{1}$.
 
Since 
$\gcd(11,\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{n})=1$ ($n$ is odd) 
it follows that $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{n}\mid x_n$ and $11\mid1\overbrace{00\ldots0}^{2k \text{ zeros}}1$.
Therefore $x_n$ is composite.

From 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\overbrace{90909\ldots0909}^{k \text{ nines}}1&\\
90909\ldots090910\, & + \\
\text{__________________}&\\
1\underbrace{00000\ldots00000}_{2k \text{ zeros}}1\;\;\;\,&
\end{array}$$
we conclude
$$
11\times\overbrace{90909\ldots09}^{k \text{ nines}}1=(10+1)\times\overbrace{90909\ldots09}^{k \text{ nines}}1=
1\overbrace{00\ldots0}^{2k \text{ zeros}}1\Longrightarrow\\ 
x_n=
\overbrace{11\ldots1}^n\times\overbrace{90909\ldots09}^{k \text{ nines}}1.
$$